# How to change Mozilla default video player?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, video, firefox-for-android, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I would like to know how to replace the default video player of Mozilla Firefox with the default Android video player on my Note 4.

My phone is not rooted.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't stream videos using mobile browsers but I guess MP4 and WEBM are still the most common formats used by websites. At least for these two extensions Firefox would play the file in its default player rather than giving you the option to choose an external app to play that file.

Thankfully, Firefox didn't choose to hard-code this behavior in its code so we can still change it. We will play with [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config). Also, my solution is tested on Firefox v37.0.2 which isn't the latest release.

### For MP4 files

1. Launch Firefox and enter `about:config` in the browser. Agree for any warning or agreement if you happen to come across.
2. In the search box, type `media.fragmented-mp4.exposed`.
3. Chane the value from `true` to `false`.

Changes would take effect immediately, else, restart Firefox.

### For WEBM files

1. Launch Firefox and enter `about:config` in the browser. Agree for any warning or agreement if you happen to come across.
2. In the search box, type `media.webm.enabled`.
3. Chane the value from `true` to `false`.

Changes would take effect immediately, else, restart Firefox.

Now whenever you would attempt to open any of the file with said extension you would get a dialog with names of all the apps that are registered to play that file. You can choose "Just Once" or "Always" for an app shown there.

Comment: Sure. :) Would you mind telling me on which Firefox release did you successfully test this answer?

Comment: On the 40.0.3 release :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Android use this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/android/addon/external-video-player/
( go to the website find the video but dont tap play instead open the firefox menu and select "play video externally" Firefox should ask which player to use select one I've tried this with VLC & MX Player both worked. ) I used Firefox 54.0.1 which is the latest Firefox atm
For desktop I saw this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/video-assistant/ which I'm not sure if it works but from the look of the reviews it does.
Reasons why you'd want to use a different video player. If the video buffers, if you're getting pop-ups when playing video.

The above method by Firelord didn't work for me ( should work for older Firefox versions & useful if the extensions aren't available for your Firefox version ) 
media.fragmented-mp4.exposed isn't on 54.0.1 but I found media.mp4.enabled & media.mediasource.mp4.enabled. I disabled one didn't work so enabled and disabled the other still didn't work also tried disabling both didn't work. Time to binge watch all seasons of adventure time lol